# Font awesome icon not showing, just box

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I tried to use an icon from font awesome but it’s not working, i copied the script link and pasted it to the head tag but it’s just showing a box.

Note: I added the actual kit number, I’m just hiding it here. You can check the image.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLLp2.png)

```html
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/my-kit-number.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
    .
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-microphone"></i>
  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Why does the script element have a period in it?

Comment: Also, that script URL is invalid. https://kit.fontawesome.com/my-kit-number.js Were you to replace `my-kit-number` with some other string?

Comment: I added the kit number, I’m just hiding it here for security purpose

Answer (score 0):

[working example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjvvF.png)

the reference to 'my-kit-number' is wrong you need to go here: https://fontawesome.com/start and add an email so then you can receive a valid script source replacing 'my-kit-number' for a valid id

Comment: I addded the actual kit number, I’m just hiding it here

Answer (score 0):

The either `.fa` or `.fas` must be used. No need for a kit this example is using a free CDN.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
     :root {
      font: 2ch/1 Consolas
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p><i class="fas fa-microphone"></i> class="fas fa-microphone"</p>
  <p><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i> class="fa fa-microphone"</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But I copied your code, went to font awesome and searched for an icon “ <i class="fa-solid fa-radio-tuner"></i>” then added it to your code but it didn’t show. Where do you search for the icon to get the code? Thanks for your input also.

Comment: Do not use `fa-solid` use `fas` or `fa`.

Comment: I think I’ve figured out the problem, the icons I’m selecting are not free, that’s why it’s not showing. Also, I used fas/fa didn’t work also.

Comment: Yeah, your'e right, it doesn't show up here: https://fontawesome.com/search?m=free, Still don't use `fa-solid` use `fa`, `fas`, or `fab` for brands.

Comment: Is there any other platform I can get those icons for free online?

Comment: Well threre's everything on https://fontawesome.com/search?m=free, There's Bootstrap: https://icons.getbootstrap.com/